# JavaFX tab pane not showing up

Tags: user-interface, javafx, fxml

I'm trying to create a simple UI using an FXML application for an app that will ultimately send a text file to another application to be used there.  My goal with the first tab in this tab pane is to allow the user to input their own group names and essentially add them to a list of all the group names they've entered.  I'm hoping to have the user type the group name into a textField, and then they click an add button, which move the group name to a textArea then goes to a new line.  I think I've gotten the action handler right but I can't test it because when I run the program nothing shows up!  Any help would be appreciated.

The Java code:

```
package pipeline.ui;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Pat
 */
public class PipelineUI extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("PipelineUI.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 1000);

        stage.setTitle("Pipeline Welcome");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

The controller code:

```
package pipeline.ui;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

/**
 *
 * @author Pat
 */
public class PipelineUIController implements Initializable {

    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private Tab groupsTab;
    @FXML
    private Button addGroup;
    @FXML
    private Button removeGroup;
    @FXML
    private Button proceedButton1;
    @FXML
    public TextArea groupsList;
    @FXML
    private TextField groupName;
    private static final String newline = "\n";

    public void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        if (groupName.getText() != "")
        {
            String name = groupName.getText();
            groupsList.appendText(name);
            groupsList.appendText(newline);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

The FXML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<TabPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity"     prefHeight="1000.0" prefWidth="1000.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE"     xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8"     fx:controller="pipeline.ui.PipelineUIController">
  <tabs>
    <Tab fx:id="groupsTab" text="Experimental Groups">
      <content>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <children>
                  <Button fx:id="addGroup" layoutX="253.0" layoutY="100.0"     mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="handleButtonAction"  text="Add Group &gt;&gt;" />
                  <Button fx:id="removeGroup" layoutX="242.0" layoutY="173.0"     mnemonicParsing="false" text="&lt;&lt; Remove Group" />
                  <Button fx:id="proceedButton1" layoutX="534.0" layoutY="332.0"     mnemonicParsing="false" text="OK" />
                  <TextArea fx:id="groupsList" layoutX="367.0" layoutY="86.0" prefHeight="200.0"     prefWidth="200.0" />
                  <TextField fx:id="groupName" layoutX="77.0" layoutY="100.0" />
                  <Text layoutX="77.0" layoutY="82.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0"     text="Add experimental groups to be examined:" />
               </children></AnchorPane>
      </content>
    </Tab>
    <Tab text="Untitled Tab 2">
      <content>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
      </content>
    </Tab>
  </tabs>
</TabPane>
```

Not sure if all of that was necessary but if anyone could help me here I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wouldn't even run for me, because you have errors in your FXML. The handler for the `addGroup` button should be `"#handleButtonAction"` (the "#" indicates it belongs to the controller, and is a script).

Additionally, since the handler method takes an `ActionEvent` as it's parameter, it should be

```
onAction="#handleButtonAction"
```

(not `onMouseClicked`).

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept the answer if it answered your question (even if you cannot upvote). In future, if you are getting exceptions when you execute your code, you should say so and post the stack trace as part of your question.